# ¿ Como puedo listar las unidades de Disco dvd de mi Pc con C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Hola estoy tratando de listas las unidades de *DVD* de mi PC con C#. Pero no se como listar solo las unidades de *DVD*.

Equipo:

```
C:\\\\  -- Unidad de disco duro
D:\\\\  -- Unidad de disco.
E:\\\\  -- Unidad de disco.
F:\\\\  -- Unidad de DVD o Cd.
G:\\\\  -- Unidad de DVD o Cd.
```

Salida:

```
1.F:\\\\  -- Unidad de DVD o Cd.
2.G:\\\\  -- Unidad de DVD o Cd.
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el método:

```
System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

Mas info en el enlace: [listar unidades](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=netframework-4.8)